# Excel 365 - Formatting a cell to highlight if other cells in same row are red in colour

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I have a worksheet which has numerous data validations. I have had to enable this worksheet to allow "paste as link" to work as some business areas will be pasting in data from a source system extract rather than manually populating each field. As this will overwrite the data validations, i have used conditional formatting to change a cell to red fill if it doesn't match one of the data validation options.
As an extra check i wanted to have a cell that would confirm if everything in that row was good, i.e. no red cells or if "Invalid Data or Required Data Missing - Please fix before proceeding".
I found a module online that needs to be ran and it presented count and sum of cells. I changed this to have message advising erros found. However it has a step where user has to select a cell that has the Fill colour the module is looking for.  I want that to be always be red, F0000AA, or refer to cell $A$2 (which has red fill).
Additionally i want to have a button in another tab and for it to only look for red cells in sheet "Test Data Request" from Rows 3 and below.
Finally not all cells are mandatory. Some may appear red as blank, but they are optional, so i also need to confirm which columns to check.
I would really appreciate of anyone could offer suggestion how to get the below script to do as i need.

1. refer to colour of cell $A$2 rather than     `Set cellsColorSample = Application.InputBox( _ "Select sample color:", "Select a cell with sample color", _ Application.Selection.Address, Type:=8)`
2. refer to sheet sheet "Test Data Request" rather than run in current sheet
3. Ignore rows 1 and 2 and only check rows 3 and below.
4. specify columns to check.

TIA

```
Sub SumCountByConditionalFormat()
    Dim indRefColor As Long
    Dim cellsColorSample As Range
    Dim cntRes As Long
    Dim sumRes
    Dim cntCells As Long
    Dim indCurCell As Long

    On Error Resume Next

    cntRes = 0
    sumRes = 0

    cntCells = Selection.CountLarge

    Set cellsColorSample = Application.InputBox( _
        "Select sample color:", "Select a cell with sample color", _
        Application.Selection.Address, Type:=8)

    If Not (cellsColorSample Is Nothing) Then
       indRefColor = cellsColorSample.Cells(1, 1).DisplayFormat.Interior.Color

       For indCurCell = 1 To (cntCells)
            If indRefColor = Selection(indCurCell).DisplayFormat.Interior.Color Then
               cntRes = cntRes + 1
               sumRes = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Selection(indCurCell), sumRes)
            End If
        Next
        MsgBox "Invalid Data or Required Data Missing - Please fix before proceeding"
    End If
End Sub
```

I have tried changing
`Set cellsColorSample = Application.InputBox( _ "Select sample color:", "Select a cell with sample color", _ Application.Selection.Address, Type:=8)`
to
`Set cellsColorSample = $A$2` but in resulted in error.
I can't see in script where it checks sheet or row, so assume it just checks whole current sheet but i don't know how to determine sheet and rows and columns. Once i have this i am able to create a button and assign module to it.

Comment: (1) You would need `Set cellsColorSample = Range("$A$2")`.